# Do we have any alternatives to "Report Generator" for merging the code coverage results in Azure pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I need to merge code coverage result for C# & Python in same pipeline.

Comment: What pipeline are you talking about? Is this Azure Devops pipeline? What code coverage analysis tools are you using?

Comment: Yes, This is  Azure Devops pipeline only.
For code coverage analysis we are using  Cobertura.